# Copy dictionary key with multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary named "session" with the following items:

```
{
    'odbs': {'steps1': {'tension': 3, 'comp': 3}},
    'odbdata': {'steps2': {'tension': 500, 'Session Step': {'Frame': 5000}, 'comp': 30}}
}
```

as you can see, I have `odbs` and `odbdata` dictionary inside `session`... and `Session Step` dictionary inside of `steps2`

I want to copy the `Session Step` dictionary  into the `steps1` dictionary, without replacing the existing values that are in there. I tried update, but its replacing the other values.  I want the 'odbs' dictionary to become

```
'odbs': {'steps1': {'tension': 3, 'Session Step': {'Frame': 5000}, 'comp': 3}}
```

Comment: basically I want the 'odbs' dictionary to become 'odbs': {'steps1': {'tension': 3, 'Session Step': {'Frame': 5000}, 'comp': 3}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure I understood the problem but how about this:

```
data = {
    'odbs': {'steps1': {'tension': 3, 'comp': 3}},
    'odbdata': {'steps2': {'tension': 500, 'Session Step': {'Frame': 5000}, 'comp': 30}}
}

data['odbs']['steps1']['Session Step'] = data['odbdata']['steps2']['Session Step']
```

I would recommend not having all these hard coded values... Maybe a couple of classes would be useful here or at least some CONST values for the key strings..

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Seeing from your question this might work

`data['odbs']['steps1']['Session Step'] = data['odbdata']['steps2']['Session Step']`

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {
    'odbs': {'steps1': {'tension': 3, 'comp': 3}},
    'odbdata': {'steps2': {'tension': 500, 'Session Step': {'Frame': 5000}, 'comp': 30}}
}

to_update = data['odbs']['steps1']

source = data['odbdata']['steps2']['Session Step']
to_update.update(source)
```

out:

```
{'odbdata': {'steps2': {'Session Step': {'Frame': 5000},
   'comp': 30,
   'tension': 500}},
 'odbs': {'steps1': {'Frame': 5000, 'comp': 3, 'tension': 3}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add they key `Session Step` to the `steps1` dictionary and initialize it to the value of `Session Step` in `steps2`.

```
session['odbs']['steps1']['Session Step'] = session['odbdata']['steps2']['Session Step']
```

That said, could you avoid having this same value in both dictionaries? Maybe by breaking off the value into a constant, or by restructuring the dict?